# Pythonic way to handle import errors

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am using a custom logging module in my project. If it is not available, I'd like to substitute it with a dummy instead of raising an `ImportError`.

Here's the code which currently does that:

```
try:
    import logger
except ImportError:
    print 'Couldn\'t load logger'

    class DummyLogger(object):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def log(self, image):
            pass

    logger = DummyLogger()
```

I don't think it's an elegant solution. It works, sure, but it ain't nice. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would it not be available?

Comment: @ArashSaidi, my program is an image processing pipeline. It takes an image, does stuff to it, and saves the results. Separately, I have a script for training the classifier I use internally. That script needs to do some preprocessing to the raw data before feeding it into the classifier. The preprocessing routines are in the module I'm talking about. That module is in a subdirectory of the main project, so when I'm running the main program, everything works fine. When I'm running the training, the module doesn't see the logger which is one level above in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it more concise quite easily:

```
try:
    import logger
except ImportError:
    print 'Couldn\'t load logger'

    class logger(object):
        @classmethod
        def log(cls, image):
            pass
```

Note that, even in your current version, the empty `__init__` should be removed -- it adds no value.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have been looking for. You could also replace `@classmethod` with `@staticmethod` to get rid of that `cls` argument.

Answer (score 6):

I would put the dummy implementation into a separate module, called `dummy_loggger`, and write:

```
try:
    import logger
except ImportError:
    import dummy_logger as logger
```

I've done this in the past with JSON parsers:

```
try:
    import ujson as json  # very fast but might not be available in some cases
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Comment: This would be a perfect solution in a more organized environment than mine. Unfortunately, this still requires an external dependency, so this is not 100% bulletproof. I am upvoting your answer but accepting @AlexMartelli's.